# JavaFX: Two values in one TableColumn

Tags: java, javafx, lambda, tableview

I have follower http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part2/ and there is a code setting values in TableColumn using lambdas:

```
firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());
lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().lastNameProperty());
```

But what to do if I have one column fullName and want to unite firstNameColumn and lastNameColumn into one fullName?

Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done by creating a `StringBinding` that depends on both first and last name:

```
fullNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> Bindings.createStringBinding(
    () -> cellData.getValue().getLastName() + ", " + cellData.getValue().getFirstName(),
    cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty(),
    cellData.getValue().lastNameProperty()
));
```

Comment: or `cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty().concat(", ").concat(cellData.getValue().lastNameProperty())` (Not really sure if that is any cleaner...)

Comment: How can I add two columns in 3rd? Columns are binded with `SimpleIntegerProperty`. I tried the same code, I only replaced to `Bindings.createIntegerBinding`. I'm looking for an example, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

The foolowing code works:

```
fullNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty() + " " + cellData.getValue().lastNameProperty());
```

Comment: Sorry, this code is actually not right. fabian's answer is good

Comment: Does that compile? The lambda expression evaluates to a `String`: you need an `ObservableValue<String>`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have different project with the different approach tánd the following compiles but this is different story <code>fullNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData ->new SimpleStringProperty (cellData.getValue().firstName() + " " + cellData.getValue().lastName()));</code>:

Comment: Yeah, that will "work", but it won't update automatically if either of the properties is changed...

Comment: The other project doesnt use properties in Person model so, I have to convert strings to properties in controller. Well the issue with this project is that half of it is not mine, but written buy third party and model Person was'r designed for javafx